# Invocation of TIBCO web service from HP Service Manager is causing error

Tags: web-services, wsdl, tibco, servicemanager

For the integration purpose, we need to consume a web service exposed by TIBCO in HP SM.

In HP SM, we consume a web service by using a utility called wsdl2js, which create JavaScript using wsdl url. I am able to use wsdl2js but when I invoke the web service, I am able to see request xml getting formed in SM but in response I am getting an error message"

```
Error calling method: doSoapRequest in class:com/hp/ov/sm/server/utility/SoapClient  
Exception(com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: 
java.security.PirvilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: 
Invalid Content-type:text/html.Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
```

In the wsdl file, there are following schemas:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created by TIBCO WSDL-->
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:ns1="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/TIGIaaS-IP085/WSDL and XSD/Schema.xsd4" xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.example.com/1372306950675/CreateUpdateIncidentImpl/BusinessProcesses/_00-InputChannels" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns0="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/TIGIaaS-IP085v0.2/WSDL and XSD/Schema.xsd2" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" name="Untitled" targetNamespace="http://xmlns.example.com/1372306950675/CreateUpdateIncidentImpl/BusinessProcesses/_00-InputChannels">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema xmlns="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/TIGIaaS-IP085v0.2/WSDL and XSD/Schema.xsd2" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/TIGIaaS-IP085v0.2/WSDL and XSD/Schema.xsd2" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
            <xs:element name="HPSM">
```

Could this error is because SM which is installed on a different unix server than TIBCO is not able to read schemas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue.
Issue was with SOAP Version. SOAP Version of wsdl provided by TIBCO was 1.2 and HP SM was expecting 1.1

SOAP 1.2 supports application/soap+xml, while SOAP 1.1 supports text/xml. That is why I was getting content-type error.